# How to add arrowhead for axes in frame?

Tags: plotting, functions

How can I add arrows for axes of frame?

 This works well if there is no frame but it doesn't work when I added frame.

```
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.2}}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.07]]
```

[image]

Adding frame:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.2}}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.07]]
```

[image]

Comment: With `PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 10}, {-1.05, 1}}` and `AxesStyle -> {{Arrowheads[0.03], Dashing[0.003], Black}, {Arrowheads[0.03], Dashing[0.003], Black}}` works fine for me.

Comment: It seems that the frame always cover the axis. If we only want to  frame,maybe add arrows by using `Epilog` or `Show` `Graphics`.

Comment: You're right, @cvgmt, that option you mention is also viable.

Comment: @E.Chan-López how can I remove the unwated plot range there? I don't want to include region where it's not needed.

Comment: I hoped this work but it doesn't. `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.01, 10}, {-0.01, 1}} , 
 AxesStyle -> {{Arrowheads[0.03], Thickness[0.005], 
    Black}, {Arrowheads[0.03], Thickness[0.005], Black}}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.2}}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[
    Graphics[{Black, Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.2}}]}], 
    Scaled[{0, 0.95}]], 
   Inset[Rotate[
     Graphics[{Black, Arrowheads[0.1], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.2}}]}], -\[Pi]/2], Scaled[{0.97, 0}]]}, 
 ImagePadding -> 60, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how would you make these axes bolder (bigger thickness)?

Comment: add `FrameStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]], 
   Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005]]}, {Directive[Black, 
    Thickness[0.01]], Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005]]}}`